# cloudfoundry vmc push crash

Tags: crash, push, cloud-foundry, vmc

**when i push my app to cloudfoundry
vmc speak to me:**

Uploading mywebsite... FAILED
Upload failed. Try again with 'vmc push
TypeError: no implicit conversion of ni
For more information, see ~/.vmc/crash

****then I open ~/.vmc/crash what the content is under****

Time of crash:
  2013-03-28 15:39:33 +0800

TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

```
multipart-post-1.2.0/lib/composite_io.rb:85:in `initialize'
multipart-post-1.2.0/lib/composite_io.rb:85:in `open'
multipart-post-1.2.0/lib/composite_io.rb:85:in `initialize'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/base.rb:57:in `new'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/v1/base.rb:57:in `upload_app'
cfoundry-0.5.2/lib/cfoundry/upload_helpers.rb:48:in `upload'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:86:in `block in upload_app'
interact-0.5.2/lib/interact/progress.rb:98:in `with_progress'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:85:in `upload_app'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:65:in `setup_new_app'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli/app/push.rb:48:in `push'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:66:in `run'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:72:in `block in invoke'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.6.2/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:142:in `call'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.6.2/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:142:in `block in create_and_save_manifest'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/callbacks.rb:74:in `with_filters'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.6.2/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:140:in `create_and_save_manifest'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.6.2/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:80:in `wrap_push'
manifests-vmc-plugin-0.6.2/lib/manifests-vmc-plugin/plugin.rb:29:in `block in <class:ManifestsPlugin>'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `instance_exec'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/command.rb:86:in `invoke'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership/base.rb:55:in `execute'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli.rb:161:in `save_token_if_it_changes'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli.rb:149:in `block in execute'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli.rb:100:in `wrap_errors'
vmc-0.5.0/lib/vmc/cli.rb:145:in `execute'
mothership-0.5.1/lib/mothership.rb:45:in `start'
vmc-0.5.0/bin/vmc:11:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/vmc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use vmc version 0.4.0, please. I faced a similar issue when using vmc 0.50, and after I changed to vmc 0.4.0, its works fine!